# Histogram Aggregation Performance issue on large dataset

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a quick question - How you guys handle working with histogram aggregation on very large datasets? When I display the same histogram on like < 7 days there's no performance issue at all.

However, the larger the time range I set, the more time it takes to get the results. Is it a common practice to store aggregated result in MySQL when it has already been processed by ElasticSearch to improve performance?

**Update:**

1. We have a cluster of 3 nodes, 8 GB of RAM each.
2. We have a monthly index rotation with 45 million documents in each one.
3. 4  CPU Core for each node.

Comment: Can you define "very large"? What's your setup (now many nodes, spec of your machines)? Help us help you, the more relevant info you give, the better your chance to get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry :) Updated my question with the details.

Comment: Thanks. What about the size of the monthly indices? How many shards per index? ... :)